# How to decimal point covert to hex point in C language

Tags: c

How to  use decimal point  covert to hex point in C language programming

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is hex point? Are you talking of double? Please give an example!

Comment: sorry!! the example:25.25 covert to hex or binary system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use printf with some good filters. Please see this example:

http://stahlforce.com/dev/index.php?tool=csc02